# Soma de matriz 2x2 em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

```py
m =  []
for l in range(0, 2):
    m.append([])
    for c in range (0, 2):
        valores = int(input("Digite valores: "))
        m[l].append(valores)
print("-"*30)
print(m)
print("-"*30)

for l in range(0, 2):
    print("|", end="")
    for c in range(0,2):
        print("{0:^5}".format(m[l][c]), end="")
    print("|")


m2 =  []
print("-"*30)
for l2 in range(0, 2):
    m2.append([])
    for c2 in range (0, 2):
        valores2 = int(input("Digite valores: "))
        m2[l2].append(valores2)
print("-"*30)
print(m2)
print("-"*30)

for l2 in range(0, 2):
    print("|", end="")
    for c2 in range(0,2):
        print("{0:^5}".format(m2[l2][c2]), end="")
    print("|")
print("-"*30)
m3 = []

soma  = m[0][0] + m[0][1]          #Somando valores da primeira matriz 
soma2 = m[1][0] + m[1][1]           #...

for l3 in range (0, 1):
        m3.append([])
        for c3 in range(0, 1):
                m3[l3].append(soma)
                m3[l3].append(soma2)

print(m3)

print("-"*30)

m4 = []

soma3 = m2[0][0] + m2[0][1]
soma4 = m2[1][0] + m2[1][1]

for l4 in range (0,1):
        m4.append([])
        for c4 in range(0, 1):
              m4[l4].append(soma3)
              m4[l4].append(soma4)  

print(m4)
print("-"*30)

mr = m3 + m4

print(mr)

for l5 in range(0, 2):
    print("|", end="")
    for c5 in range(0,2):
        print("{0:^5}".format(mr[l5][c5]), end="")
    print("|")
print("-"*30)
```

"Crie uma matriz 2x2 e faça a soma das duas"
Como mostra o código, eu criei duas matrizes, mas não estou conseguindo efetuar a soma das mesmas. Criei uma matriz pra armazenar, mas está printando a matriz na posição diferente.

Comment: A ideia de definir uma matriz total me parece plausível. Como fez o código para isso e quais os erros que obteve?

Comment: Então, fiz uma matriz pra fazer isso, mas quando compilava ela armazenava a soma das linhas da primeira matriz apenas e acabava ignorando a segunda matriz.

Comment: Poderia adicionar o código na pergunta?

Comment: Um momento, estou refazendo as linhas aqui, assim que terminar irei postar aqui.